# Docker ignoring local dns settings

Tags: docker, jenkins, dns, kubernetes, resolve

I launched a `jenkins-k8s-slave` which should pull from a local registry. Why does docker ignore the local DNS settings (`/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf`) managed by kubernetes?

When I do:

`docker pull service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:5000/test:latest`

I get: `dial tcp: lookup service.namespace.svc.cluster.local: no such host`

but this works:

`curl https://service.namespace.svc.cluster.local:5000/v2/_catalog -k`
`{"repositories":[...]}`

Comment: have you configured docker to use the dns

Comment: what do you mean with configuring? can you give an example? It should inherit from the host setting right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to configure docker to use your dns , whatever that may be , in this case , it seems that you need to tell docker to use the kubernetes dns:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23910

Example config:

```
cat /etc/docker/daemon.json

{
    "hosts": [ "unix:///var/run/docker.sock","tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
    "live-restore": true,
    "tls": true,
    "tlscacert": "/etc/docker/ssl/ca.pem",
    "tlscert": "/etc/docker/ssl/cert.pem",
    "tlskey": "/etc/docker/ssl/key.pem",
    "tlsverify": true,
    "dns":["172.21.1.100","172.16.1.100"]
}
```

See Also:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-pull-not-using-correct-dns-server-when-private-registry-on-vpn/11117/29